# Saving email headers as .msg

Tags: outlook, header, msg

Dear StackOverflowers.

I know a few programming languages, but unfortunately VBA is not one of them.
I'm trying to make a script that saves the headers from selected mails in Outlook as .msg-files.
I found a script that opens the headers as new messages, but how to I save them as e.g. **[senders domain]_[date recieved].msg** instead of opening them as new mails?

The script that I have:

```
Sub ViewInternetHeader()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem, olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strHeader As String

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        strHeader = GetInetHeaders(olItem)

        Set olMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With olMsg
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            .Body = strHeader
            .Display
        End With
    Next
    Set olMsg = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetInetHeaders(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    ' Purpose: Returns the internet headers of a message.'
    ' Written: 4/28/2009'
    ' Author:  BlueDevilFan'
    ' //techniclee.wordpress.com/
    ' Outlook: 2007'
    Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
    GetInetHeaders = olkPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS)
    Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.SaveAs) method which saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used. For example:

```
Sub SaveAsTXT() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim objItem As Object 

 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector 
 If Not TypeName(myItem) = "Nothing" Then 
 Set objItem = myItem.CurrentItem 
 strname = objItem.Subject 
 'Prompt the user for confirmation 
 Dim strPrompt As String 
 strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the item? " & _ 
 "If a file with the same name already exists, " & _ 
 "it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
 If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
 objItem.SaveAs Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & strname & ".txt", olTXT 
 End If 
 Else 
 MsgBox "There is no current active inspector." 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, Eugene. I wasn't allowed to comment your answer, as there were too many characters, so I "answered" my original post.

Answer (score 0):

So you want an MSG file that has no recipients, attachments, subject, etc, only the MIME headers as the body? Why do you want the MSG format then?

You can create an populate a text file using the [Scripting.FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) and use its [CreateTextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method) method.

Comment: I want to create a script that makes .msg files with the headers of emails. It is in order to send the headers of my spammail to my mail host, so that they can block it.
I don't know any VBA, so I don't really have any idea what the different classes and method do. :(

Comment: They told me to send the headers as msg-files. I don't know why. I suppose they could have used .txt-files as well.

Comment: I could understand MSG file if they wanted the whole thing, including the body/recipients/attachments *and* the MIME headers, but MIME headers alone in a standalone MSG makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Eugene.
I managed to put in your code.
But it doesn't give the file a name, it's only called ".msg", and it doesn't work, when I try to select more than one email.
Also, how do I avoid, that it opens a new mail with the header?

I have this script now:

```
Sub ViewInternetHeader()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem, olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strHeader As String

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        strHeader = GetInetHeaders(olItem)

        Set olMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With olMsg
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            .Body = strHeader
            .Display
        End With
    Next
    Set olMsg = Nothing

    Dim myItem As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objItem As Object

    Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector
    If Not TypeName(myItem) = "Nothing" Then
        Set objItem = myItem.CurrentItem
        strname = objItem.SenderEmailAddress
        'Prompt the user for confirmation
        Dim strPrompt As String
        strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the item? " & _
        "If a file with the same name already exists, " & _
        "it will be overwritten with this copy of the file."
        If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            objItem.saveas "C:\temp\" & strname & ".msg", OLTXT
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "There is no current active inspector."
    End If

End Sub

Function GetInetHeaders(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
    GetInetHeaders = olkPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS)
    Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I'd suggest marking the answer to your original post and posting another question in a separate thread so others could find the answer easily.

Comment: But it is the same question. It has just not been answered yet. Should I delete this post, and create a new one with the updated info?